# Populate variable dynamically with data from another database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following snippet of code:

```
   DECLARE @uidSecurity NVARCHAR(25), 
        @sql NVARCHAR(500), 
        @DBName nvarchar(50)= 'DBNAME', 
        @SecurityGroup nvarchar(10) = 'NEWGROUP'

   declare @Winlogon table (
    uidFileNumber nvarchar(25))

   select @sql = ' INSERT INTO @Winlogon
        SELECT uidFileNumber 
        FROM [' + @DBName + '].dbo.SERCURE 
        WHERE code = ''' + @SecurityGroup + ''''

   exec sp_executesql @sql

   SELECT uidFileNumber FROM @WINLOGON
```

I am trying to populate a local variable with data from another database which will change with every loop of the code.  My problem is that it does not recognise the @winlogon table variable as being declared when inside the @SQL statement.  Is there another way that this can be done?

It works if I pass a static database name into the code as follows:

```
 DECLARE @uidSecurity NVARCHAR(25), 
   @sql NVARCHAR(500), 
   @sql1 NVARCHAR(500), 
   @SecurityGroup nvarchar(10) = 'NEWGROUP'

   declare @Winlogon table (
    uidFileNumber nvarchar(25))

   INSERT INTO @Winlogon
   SELECT uidFileNumber 
   FROM [STATICDB].dbo.SERCURE 
   WHERE code = @SecurityGroup

   SELECT uidFileNumber FROM @WINLOGON
```

But I need to pass a different database name via another local variable every time the code run with a while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use INSERT-EXEC:

```
 DECLARE @uidSecurity NVARCHAR(25), 
     @sql NVARCHAR(500), 
     @sql1 NVARCHAR(500), 
     @SecurityGroup nvarchar(10) = 'NEWGROUP'

 DECLARE @Winlogon TABLE (
     uidFileNumber nvarchar(25))

 SET @sql = N'SELECT uidFileNumber 
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) + '.dbo.SERCURE 
    WHERE code = ' + QUOTENAME(@SecurityGroup, '''')

 INSERT INTO @Winlogon(uidFileNumber)
 EXEC(@sql)
```